# set column value to first value meeting conditions across columns

Tags: r, mutate

I have a dataframe with columns that start with "dx". I want to create another column called `primary`. If the value in all of the columns that start with "dx" is `"I629"` or `NA`, I want the value of `primary` to be `"Unspecified"`. Otherwise, I want the it to be the first non-`"I629"` value.

My desired output:

```
dx1  dx2  dx3 dx4 dx5 primary
I629 NA   NA  NA  NA  Unspecified
S065 NA   NA  NA  NA  S065
I629 S066 NA  NA  NA  S066
I629 I629 NA  NA  NA  Unspecified
```

Comment: Do you mean the value in all of the _rows_ is "I629" or NA?

Comment: I mean if the value in dx1 - dx5 is I629 or NA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A tidyverse solution: create a helper dataframe where `"I629"` is replaced with `NA` across all `Dx` columns; use `dplyr::coalesce()` to take the first non-`NA` value (or `"Unspecified"` if all `NA`); and finally bind the new `primary` column to your original dataframe.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

primary_dx <- dat %>% 
  mutate(
    across(starts_with("dx"), \(col) na_if(col, "I629")),
    primary = coalesce(!!!select(., starts_with("dx")), "Unspecified")
  ) %>% 
  select(primary)

bind_cols(dat, primary_dx)
```

```
# A tibble: 4 × 6
  dx1   dx2   dx3   dx4   dx5   primary    
  <chr> <chr> <lgl> <lgl> <lgl> <chr>      
1 I629  NA    NA    NA    NA    Unspecified
2 S065  NA    NA    NA    NA    S065       
3 I629  S066  NA    NA    NA    S066       
4 I629  I629  NA    NA    NA    Unspecified
```

Answer (score 1):

```r
data <- data.frame(dx1 = c("I629", "S065", "I629", "I629"), dx2 = c(NA, 
NA, "S066", "I629"), dx3 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA), dx4 = c(NA, NA, 
NA, NA), dx5 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA))


data$primary <- apply(data, 1, \(x)
 if (all(is.na(x) | all(x=="I629" , na.rm = T) )) "Unspecified" 
 else x[which(x != "I629")[1]])

data
#>    dx1  dx2 dx3 dx4 dx5     primary
#> 1 I629 <NA>  NA  NA  NA Unspecified
#> 2 S065 <NA>  NA  NA  NA        S065
#> 3 I629 S066  NA  NA  NA        S066
#> 4 I629 I629  NA  NA  NA Unspecified
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try, which uses `apply` to look across rows to see if all 5 columns contain either `NA` or `I629`, then uses a simple `ifelse` to categorize the outcome:

```
df$primary <- apply(df, 1, function(x) ifelse(sum(x == "I629" | is.na(x)) == 5, "Unspecified", x[1]))
```

Output:

```
#    dx1  dx2 dx3 dx4 dx5     primary
# 1 I629 <NA>  NA  NA  NA Unspecified
# 2 S065 <NA>  NA  NA  NA        S065
# 3 I629 S066  NA  NA  NA        I629
# 4 I629 I629  NA  NA  NA Unspecified
```

Data

```
df <- read.table(text = "dx1   dx2   dx3   dx4   dx5
I629 NA    NA    NA    NA
S065 NA    NA    NA    NA
I629 S066  NA    NA    NA
I629 I629 NA   NA    NA", header = TRUE)
```